# Can “even” follow the word “that”

Tags: grammar, word-usage

For example:

> Anything that **even** looks like a baby is also cute.

Is it correct?

Comment: Yes: "even" is a focusing adverb. "That even looks like a baby" is a relative clause modifying "anything".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You might say:

> Babies are cute. Anything that even looks like a baby is also cute.

Spoken aloud, there would be stress on *looks*. Another way of expressing it is "so much as":

> Babies are cute. Anything that **so much as** looks like a baby is also cute.

Or to give another illustrative example:

> The boss is a real tyrant. Anyone who **even** looks at him wrong gets chewed out.
>   The boss is a real tyrant. Anyone who **so much** as looks at him wrong gets chewed out.

It suggests that what comes after it isn't necessarily *enough* to produce the reaction that it does, or is not quite the same as something else. It tends to suggest that reactions are excessive or surprising.

Comment: Your last example the comma should be after wrong not after him...ie “The boss is a real tyrant. Anyone who so much as looks at him wrong, gets chewed out”.